# How to simulate modal dialog UI behaviour in a modeless dialog?

Tags: winapi, mfc

Is there an easy way to display a dialog modelessly while retaining the UI blocking a modal dialog provides?

I want to stop a user interacting with other dialogs/controls when the dialog is shown, but let the application carry on running. Is there a way to set a dialog as "exclusive focus" or something like that?

Comment: Did you try with `EnableWindow(mainWnd, FALSE)` and then `CreateDialog(mainWnd, ...)`?

Comment: I'm working in MFC but I think your question transfers - however I'm not sure how easy it is to get `mainWnd` from the place the dialog is launched. Feel free to submit an answer based on this though.

Comment: Well, you need the owner window to create the dialog anyway. Or if you use the default main window, just use `AfxGetMainWnd()`. I didn't post as answer because I don't know if it will work or look weird, just an idea...

Comment: We're passing NULL as the parent window which MSDN says: "If it is NULL, the dialog object's parent window is set to the main application window". So `AfxGetMainWnd()` probably is appropriate. I'd say post it as an answer, but note it's untested.

Comment: *"I want to stop a user interacting with other dialogs/controls when the dialog is shown, but let the application carry on running."* In other words: You want a modal dialog. What am I missing?

Comment: Well: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/02/18/376080.aspx But since asking this question I'm learned my understanding of the internals was not quite correct. However for one concrete example where modal behaves differently: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26760980/modal-mfc-dialog-not-shown-due-to-idle-checks-in-cwndrunmodalloop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no easy way to do what you want.

If you really want to go the route you describe, I recommend first reading the whole 'modality' series on Raymond Chen's blog. First installment is on http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/02/18/376080.aspx .

However, this seems like an instance of the XY problem. What is it that you are trying to do? Get the main application to keep updating itself? If so, I think (with the information we are given) that calling AfxPumpMessage() will do what you want. Or do you want to continue processing data in the main application? Then you'll save yourself a world of hurt by using a worker thread.

Answer (score 1):

Untested, but you can try do disable the owner window (the app. main window), create a modeless dialog, and then, when the dialog is closed, enable it again:

To disable the main window:

```
AfxGetMainWnd()->EnableWindow(FALSE);
```

To create the modal/non-blocking dialog:

```
dlg->Create(resId)
```

And to enable it again, on the OnClose event, or similar:

```
AfxGetMainWnd()->EnableWindow(TRUE);
```

There may be other details in a modal dialog that I'm not aware of. If you are willing to investigate, read the source code of MFC's `CDialog::DoModal()`. If I remember correctly, this MFC function simulates a modal-blocking dialog using the modeless Win32 API `CreateDialog*()` in order to implement global accelerators, hooks, messages and the like.

Comment: I think this basically _is_ the same solution Chen provides in the blog Roel links to (Old New Thing, Modality Part 1).

Answer (score -1):

Here is possible answer to your question:

You could disable all the other controls in the application then re-enable them after the dialog has finished.

Use this callback

```
BOOL CALLBACK EnableDisableAllChildren ( HWND hwnd, LPARAM lp ) 
{
    ::EnableWindow ( hwnd, (BOOL)lp );

    return TRUE;
}
```

With a Call to

```
  EnumChildWindows ( HWNDToYourApp, EnableDisableAllChildren, true );
```

Do Modaless Dialog

```
  EnumChildWindows ( HWNDToYourApp, EnableDisableAllChildren, false );
```

Something different to think about.

Comment: When the dialog manager closes the dialog, it transfers input focus to an appropriate window. A potential candidate must be enabled. Since all child windows of your application are still disabled when the dialog closes, you just blew your last chance to regain input focus. This application will not expose a usable keyboard interface.

Comment: @IInspectable  He could to the Disabling and Enabling inside the Dialog itself

Comment: I was commenting on the solution as posted. If it comes with a disclaimer along the lines of *"has to be fixed to make it work"*, it fails to be a solution. While this defect can be worked around, it is not the only one: Unconditionally enabling all child windows when the dialog closes will also enable windows that were initially disabled, or were disabled as a result of user interaction with the dialog. The solution just turned into a challenge to fix.